Is a 'Back' Button Necessary on the Login Page after Navigating from the Landing Page?
I am designing a user journey that includes the following flow:
Users start on the Partner's Website.
They can navigate to a section that mimics the Landing Page, which contains a button linking to the actual landing page.
The Landing Page features a prominent Get Started CTA button in the banner, followed by a Featured Products section, where each tile has a Quick Quote button that directs users to the Quick Quote Page.
Below the tiles, there is an Access Now button.
Clicking on the Get Started or Access Now buttons takes users to the Registration Form, which serves as a login page for members, with a Register CTA button for new applicants.
Additionally, from the Quick Quote Page, there is also a Get Started CTA that directs users to the registration process.
Given this structure, a stakeholder suggested adding a 'Back' button on the Login Page to allow users to return to the Landing Page. However, I’m unsure about the necessity of this button for the following reasons:
Existing Navigation: The browser's native back button already allows users to navigate back to the previous page. Does adding a dedicated button enhance the user experience or create redundancy?
Design Clutter: A 'Back' button may clutter the clean design of the login page. Is it better to keep the interface streamlined?
User Familiarity: Most users are accustomed to using the browser's navigation. Does providing an additional button align with user expectations, or could it confuse less experienced users?
I would appreciate your insights on whether a 'Back' button should be added to the login page, considering the potential redundancy and design implications.

Related question: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74311/should-a-web-based-ui-rely-on-the-browser-back-button

This opinion is personal, it is not verified by any study beyond my experience

First of all, after reading the explanation of how navigation works, it is not clear to me whether what you need is a Back, Close, Cancel or Previous button. The analysis I am doing is only about the Back button.
When googling, in many forums you can read compendiums and countless reasons why you should NOT put a Back button on a web page, among which those listed in the question appear.
I am of the opposite opinion, perhaps because I point to the side of design, coherence and visual perception, reasons that by extension usually contribute positively to usability. If the Back button is a simple icon or small button in the upper left corner of the screen, it does not make any sense. But if, on the contrary, it is part of the visual graphic systematization of the design, I am very much in favor.

A practical example, this is the group of buttons at the base of the pages of my website in mobile version: back button, social media sharing buttons and go to top button.

And this is the same capture but where you can see the browser's back button at the bottom, where I think any explanation about which of the two offers a better visual response and greater functional immediacy is unnecessary:


Thank you! It make sense!
